# actionBar produce NullPointerException

Tags: android, tabs

I am getting this error ***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference***

```
package com.surbhi.oopscourier.driver;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.surbhi.oopscourier.R;

public class GeneralFiles extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_files);

        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};
        //Add New Tab
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Android").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("iOS").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Windows").setTabListener(tabListener));

    }




}
```

Action bar problem and tabs are not displaying

```
com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 1189
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.surbhi.oopscourier.driver.GeneralFiles}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
at com.surbhi.oopscourier.driver.GeneralFiles.onCreate(GeneralFiles.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Action bar exception and please also show me the code of manifest to display action bar and theme also. Tabs are not displaying and these are the errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION\_MODE\_TABS) produce NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581876/actionbar-setnavigationmodeactionbar-navigation-mode-tabs-produce-nullpointere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.